# how to combine two dataframes with different levels of index?

Tags: python-3.x

My first DataFrame code:

```
 data = {'Sr.No.': Sr_no,
    'CompanyNames': Company_Names,
    'YourChoice1': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
    'YourChoice2': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']}


 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Sr.No.', 'CompanyNames','YourChoice1','YourChoice2'])
```

The output of this dataframe in .csv file is:

[image: Output of 1st DataFrame]

Second DataFrame code:

```
 data = {'BB': {'Field1': {'Previous Data': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                      'Current Data': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']},

           'Field2': {'Previous Data': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                      'Current Data': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']},

           'Field3': {'Previous Data': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                      'Current Data': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']}
           },


    'MD': {'Field1': {'Previous Data': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                      'Current Data': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']},

           'Field2': {'Previous Data': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                      'Current Data': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']}
           }
    }

 form = {(outerKey,midKey,innerKey): values   for outerKey, midDict in data.items()   for midKey, innerDict in midDict.items()  for innerKey, values in innerDict.items()}

 df.to_csv('CSV_File_Name.csv', index=False)
```

The output of this dataframe is:

[image: Output of 2nd DataFrame]

I want to combine these dataframes such that I get the following desired output:

[image: Desired Output]